# Store DataTable in a Varbinary column in SQL and retrieve Varbinary back into DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, varbinary

I have a DataTable containing all the information I need for processing. I plan to transform it into a byte[] array and store it in a Varbinary column in SQL.

Here is my code, but I don't know how to directly convert it into bytes since I use a DataSet for it:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Age");
DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Gender");

dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);

//adding of inner datatable to outer datatable
dt.Rows.Add("John", "23", "Male");
dt.Rows.Add("Gretchen", "25", "Female");
dt.Rows.Add("Jordan", "28", "Male");

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
string xmlString = ds.GetXml();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlString);
xml.Save(ms);
byte[] xmlBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Here is the code I use to store the data. I'm using Dapper in calling the Stored Procedure:

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TEST_DB")))
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("@Input_ByteData", xmlBytes);

                connection.Execute("dbo.uspInsertDataIntoVarbinaryColumn", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
```

> How do I store a DataTable into a Varbinary column in SQL Server and retrieve it from SQL back into a DataTable?

Comment: Could you show us you inserted table information?

Comment: Is there a reason for not just inserting the data into a DB table?  That makes it queryable whereas your current approach does not.  Your example data is all text, is there a reason for wanting Varbinary? or XML for that matter?

Comment: Added insert table code.

Comment: The reason why I refrained from inserting the data into a DB Table is because I don't need to query the contents of the DataTable from SQL. I will only be using that data in C#, and I am using SQL to store that data until the time comes when I need it. So it's more of storing the data for future use.

Comment: How do you now which `DataSet` belong this user? because there isn't a PK or key to find Binary of` DataSet`

Comment: I need not store the DataTable into the DateSet since I will only be using SQL to store DataTable information inside a single column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two separate issues here:

1. how to get a `DataTable` to/from a BLOB
2. how to store/fetch a BLOB from SQL Server

IMO they should be kept separate.

The first is relatively simple - it can be done a little more efficiently than your code using `SerializationFormat.Binary`, which requires `BinaryFormatter`, but:

```
static DataTable FromBytes(byte[] arr)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
    {
        return (DataTable)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
static byte[] ToBytes(DataTable table)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        table.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, table);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }            
}
```

Then all you need to do is send a `byte[]` to/from SQL-Server, which works in Dapper just by... passing a `byte[]` as a parameter, or reading it out as a column.

Note, however, that storing a `DataTable` in a column in a SQL table sounds a bit ... "inner platform".

Comment: Do you know of any possible problems that may arise due to my approach in storing DataTable in a SQL table? I'm not going to do anything SQL-related to the DataTable, like querying etc. I will only be using it in C# once I convert it into a DataTable. So I am literally just storing it in the SQL table.

Comment: @thecodeexplorer it'll be very hard to work with it if you later need that data from node.js or Java or something; other than that... you should be fine

Comment: oh, I see. Because it's in a DataTable format. thanks for pointing that out.